# ngModel doesn't work properly in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, angular2-ngmodel

I faced a problem with `ngModel` directive. I have an `input` `<td><input type="text" ([ngModel])="desc"></td>` in which I assigned value of that `input` to the variable called `desc`. Then in `component` I just want to print it in the console by:

```
addItem(){
    console.log('=======', this.desc);
  }
```

The method `addItem()` is decalred in `html` file below the `input`:

```
   <td>
            <i
              class="fa fa-plus-square add-button"
              (click)="addItem()">
            </i>
   </td>
```

The thing which I get back is: `======= undefined` in the console. Can anyone tell me why I got this? In diffrent place of this app I'm also using `ngModel` and everything works good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the data-binding operators ( and [ is wrong, if you want dual binding to work properly, you need to remember the famous sentence "Banana in a box" so you need to write [(ngModel)] it's like a banana in a box [()] .

For information, [ is for view to controller binding and ( for the inverse.

Comment: Ok, so I have changed a little bit and now it looks like: `<td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem.description"></td>` and created just a new object in `component` called `newItem`. Is there any way to omit the problem with `Cannot read property 'description' of undefined` because of the field `description` in `newItem` which has never been created?

Comment: Of course, but you will have to create a class that contains all the properties of newItem. Let's say that your class is called Item, so in your controller, you just have to instantiate an object of that class: `newItem : Item = new Item();`